# Eigenvalues of a real square matrix with ones on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

What can be said about the eigenvalue / singular values of a real square matrix with all ones on the diagonal?   I don't want to assume anything about the remaining entries.   If the matrix is symetric, is there anything more than can be said?   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the characteristic polynomial splits, then the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace of the matrix.

Suppose the matrix is $n\times n$. We don't know a priori that all of the eigenvalues are real, but the sum of the eigenvalues (when viewed as a matrix over $\mathbb{C}$) is $n$.

If the matrix is symmetric then the eigenvalues will be real numbers (by the Real Spectral Theorem) in addition to summing to $n$.

Comment: Thank you.   What can be said about the singular values?

Comment: In fact, this is **all** that can be said about the eigenvalues.  It is known that any matrix is unitarily similar to a matrix with a constant value on the diagonal.  Thus, every $n \times n$ matrix with trace $n$ is similar to a matrix with $1$s on the diagonal, and every $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with trace $n$ is similar to a symmetric matrix with $1$s on the diagonal.

Comment: @Joel the matrix is symmetric, then its singular values are the absolute values of the eigenvalues.  Other than that, all we have are the usual inequalities relating singular values to eigenvalues.  See, e.g., page 55 of Bhatia's *Matrix Analysis*.